# try to connect to gcm server but get SASLError using X-OAUTH2: incorrect-encoding

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, xmpp

I am trying to connect to gcm server using XMPP protocol and smake library.
here is some piece of code

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config =
            XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
            .setServiceName(GCM_SERVER)
             .setHost(GCM_SERVER)
             .setCompressionEnabled(false)
             .setPort(GCM_PORT)
             .setConnectTimeout(30000)
             .setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled)
             .setSendPresence(false)
             .setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault())
            .build();
XMPPTCPConnection connection  = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
connection.connect();
connection.login(pojectId + "@gcm.googleapis.com" , apiKey);
```

when trying to login this exception occured:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLErrorException: SASLError using X-OAUTH2: incorrect-encoding
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticationFailed(SASLAuthentication.java:365)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1033)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$200(XMPPTCPConnection.java:937)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:952)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

here is list of jars I use:

[image]

stacktrace log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't initialize the configured debugger!
at org.jivesoftware.smack.debugger.ReflectionDebuggerFactory.create(ReflectionDebuggerFactory.java:88)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackConfiguration.createDebugger(SmackConfiguration.java:199)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.initDebugger(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:893)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.initReaderAndWriter(XMPPTCPConnection.java:653)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.initConnection(XMPPTCPConnection.java:612)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:834)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.connect(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:360)
at com.amnmoj.GcmPushServer.connect(GcmPushServer.java:258)
at com.amnmoj.GcmPushServer.main(GcmPushServer.java:391)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.debugger.ReflectionDebuggerFactory.create(ReflectionDebuggerFactory.java:86)
... 8 more
 Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection, but class was expected
at org.jivesoftware.smackx.debugger.EnhancedDebugger.addInformationPanel(EnhancedDebugger.java:562)
at org.jivesoftware.smackx.debugger.EnhancedDebugger.createDebug(EnhancedDebugger.java:167)
at org.jivesoftware.smackx.debugger.EnhancedDebugger.<init>(EnhancedDebugger.java:147)
... 13 more
```

Comment: Could you show us a stream trace by setting `SmackConfiguration.DEBUG` to true? More about at https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/How-to-ask-for-help,-report-an-issue-and-possible-solve-the-problem-yourself

Comment: @Flow I edit my question, waiting for your answer

Comment: I just noticed that you include `smack.jar` together with the smack 4.1 jars. Don't do that. That is likely causing the IncompatibleClassChangeError. Use a build system able to resolve Maven dependencies like gradle.